# check if div with scrollbar is currently readed by user

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with a scrollbar which contains a logfile.
I fetch the newest log every 5000ms from the server by running a timer which does an ajax request to the server.

However, each time when I am reading and scrolling down the div, and the ajax request refreshes the div with the new content, then I am at the top of the text again and have to read all again.

So I need to check somehow if the user is reading at the moment, and clear the interval if he does.

I know that I could just create a toggle so the user can clear the interval manually, but I wan't to try a more intelligent approach.

My approach would be to check inside the timer, wheter the div is focused or not and if true, clear the Interval.

```
        getLogs = setInterval
        (
            function()
            {       
                if ($("div#log").is(":focus"))
                {
                     clearInterval(getLogs);
                }
                else
                {
                     //ajax request
                }
            },
            5000
        );
```

But `$("div#log").is(":focus")` always returns `false`.
I also tried `$("div#log").is(":active")` but this is not defined.

Comment: Why not store the scroll-position and restore it after the update?

Comment: I was not aware that this is possible. Good idea But what if the log is empty after the update and the last stored position is 2500 for example? Do i have to count the lines from the log and send it back to the client so i can check for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use jQuery's .scrollTop() method to check whether scrollTop !== 0 in which case you can assume the user has scrolled within the element and is currently reading it.

```
getLogs = setInterval
    (
        function()
        {       
            if ($("div#log").scrollTop() > 0)
            {
                 clearInterval(getLogs);
            }
            else
            {
                 //ajax request
            }
        },
        5000
    );
```

You could then introduce some logic to reinstate the timer either after a certain amount of time (assuming at some point the user will move on - quite a quick, but unstable solution) or by checking whether your log-file height is same as .scrollTop() + containing div height in which case the user has read to the end of the document.